# Derive an expression to find the cardinality of the union of 4 sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know the expression is:

$$ n \left(A\cup B\cup C\cup D\right) = $$

$$\Bigl(n\left(A\right)+ n(B)+ n(C)+ n(D)\Bigr)-
$$$$
\Bigl(n(A\cap B)+ n(A\cap C)+ n(A\cap D)+ n(B\cap C)+ n(B\cap D)+ n(C\cap D)\Bigr)+$$$$
\Bigl(n(A\cap B\cap C)+ n(A\cap C\cap D)+ n(A\cap B\cap D)+ n(B\cap C\cap D)\Bigr)-$$$$
n(A\cap B\cap C\cap D)  $$

But how is this derived?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't the formula.  Some of those $+$ signs should be $-$ signs.

In the calculations below, all sets are finite.

One way to do it is to start from $$n(A\cup B)=N(A)+N(B)-n(A\cap B)\tag1$$  On the right-hand side, $n(A)+n(B)$ clearly counts every element of $A\cup B$, but it counts elements of $A\cap B$ twice, so we must subtract them.

For $3$ sets, let $B = C\cup D$ in $(1)$.  Then we have
$$\begin{align}
n(A\cup C\cup D )&=
n(A\cup (C\cup D))\\
&= n(A)+n(C\cup D)-n(A\cap(C\cup D)\\
&=n(A)+n(C)+n(D)-n(C\cap D)-n((A\cap C)\cup(A\cap D))\\
&=n(A)+n(C)+n(D)-n(C\cap D)-(n(A\cap C)+n(A\cap D)\\&\quad-n((A\cap C)\cap(A\cap D)))\\
&=n(A)+n(C)+n(D)-n(C\cap D)-n(A\cap C)-n(A\cap D)\\&\quad+n(A\cap C\cap D)\tag2
\end{align}$$
To get the formula for $4$ sets, we can substitute $E\cup F$ for $D$ in $(2)$.

The general formula, for $n$ sets, is called the [principle of inclusion and exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  A proof is given [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/combinatorics/InclusionExclusion.shtml).  It consists simply of verifying that for $k=1,2,\dots,n$ an elements that appears in exactly $k$ of the sets is counted exactly once.  This is because the element is counted in $\binom kj$ of the terms involving exactly $j$ sets, $j=1,\cdots,k$.  So it is counted $$\binom k1-\binom k2+\cdots+(-1)^{k-1}\binom kk=\binom k0=1$$ times, by the binomial theorem.

Comment: thanks! this cleared my doubt :)